# Modify function to use list comprehision in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have got a function:

```
def euler9():
    for b in range(1, 500):
        a = (500000 - 1000 * b) / (1000 - b)
        if a % 1 == 0:
            print(b * a * (1000 - a - b))
```

And I want to make it in one line like

```
x*x for x in range(1,1)
```

This is what I have done:

```
def euler9():
    print([b * a * (1000 - a - b) for b in range(1, 500) for a in (500000 - 1000 * b) / (1000 - b) if a % 1 == 0])
```

but I do not know what am I doing wrong. I have got an error:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: It looks like you're trying to see whether `1000 - b` divides `500000 - 1000 * b`. If so, you should check whether `(500000 - 1000 * b) % (1000 - b) == 0`, rather than performing a floating-point division and checking whether the result has a fractional part. Floating-point operations involve rounding error that you shouldn't subject yourself to for a purely-integer operation.

Comment: It looks way worse in a list comprehension and it will be less efficient since you have to calculate the same things twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` is for iteration (looping). When you say `for b in range(1, 500)` you are not setting `b = range(1, 500)`, since that would make `b` a list. You are extracting each individual value and using them one at a time. You cannot extract values from a float.

Python has no syntax for simple assignment in list comprehensions, but you can work around that by putting the value inside a single-element list, thus making it iterable:

```
[b * a * (1000 - a - b) for b in range(1, 500) for a in [(500000 - 1000 * b) / (1000 - b)] if a % 1 == 0]
```

(You can put `print(...)` around the initial expression if you want but I assume you want to actually use the values)

But don't ever do this, it's hard to read and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here `for a in (500000 - 1000 * b) / (1000 - b)` you are trying to iterate over a float number which is the result of a devision. 
As a quick fix try this:

```
def euler9():
    print([b * ((500000 - 1000 * b) / (1000 - b)) * (1000 - ((500000 - 1000 * b) / (1000 - b)) - b) 
           for b in range(1, 500) if ((500000 - 1000 * b) / (1000 - b)) % 1 == 0])
```

But, as you see it gets a bit messy that way, and it is recommended to use loops instead of list comprehension when things get complicated.

Comment: but here you duplicate the same equalation

Answer (score -1):

Turn it into a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) by changing `print` to `yield`:

```
def euler9():
    for b in range(1, 500):
        a = (500000 - 1000 * b) / (1000 - b)
        if a % 1 == 0:
            yield (b * a * (1000 - a - b))
```

Then you can access it as a list comprehension:

```
print [x for x in euler9()]
```